# Variable imported, but gives import error when used ReactJS Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, javascript-import

I am working on `ReactJS` and `Redux`. I have a file named `actionTypes.js`. In this file, I have the following `export` statement:

`export const REGISTER_USER = 'REGISTER_USER';`

Now, I import it in `registerReducer.js` with the statement:

`import {REGISTER_USER} from '../actions/actionTypes';`

However, when I use this `REGISTER_USER` variable in my `registerReducer.js` file, it gives the following error:

`Attempted import error: 'REGISTER_USER' is not exported from '../actions/actionTypes'.`

When I only import `REGISTER_USER` but not use it, then the warning `declared but not used` is issued. I am unable to understand the problem.

**Note:** All the paths and variable names are correct. I have verified it many times.

Comment: May be you have issues with bundling? Are you using webpack? Please share details

Answer (score 1):

It might have been a bundling issue with webpack. I have ran into this issue before using react v16.10.2. I haven't seen this issue in a while though. A simple restarting/rebundling might have solved this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. No code changes were needed. I just created another dummy variable in `actionTypes.js` and then removed that variable. Everything remained same and the code executed successfully. God knows how it happened.

Comment: If you've just one export then you have to call named import, like `import REGISTER_USER`, but when you've more than one, then it's object of exports, and hence `import {REGISTER_USER}`. In future, if you know this, this will help you solve issues.

Comment: @Bikas I was doing the same. As I have in my answer, that the problem was solved without any changes. Now, my new question may be why it executed without any changes. :P

Comment: Maybe you forgot to save actionTypes.js file when adding the REGISTER_USER const XD